# Black screen with installation Acer 4736Z

Tags: 12.04, 11.04, 10.04, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I presently work with 10.04 on my Acer 4736Z.  I tried upgrading to 11.04.  The installation was successful, but there was some problem such that the screen remained dark.  I noticed the successful installation because I could see the opening screen at certain angles in bright light, however the overall appearance of the screen was dark. Ultimately I had to reinstall 10.04. I want to now upgrade to 12.04 LTS, but I remain apprehensive. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to download the ISO image from the [Ubuntu website](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and follow the instructions to install it from Live USB or CD/DVD, whichever you prefer.

This is quicker and there is a lower chance of package errors later on. Once you boot from your installation media, wait for the screen that is dark purple with a human and a keyboard, then press Enter. After that, hit F6. In the menu you get then, select "nomodeset". After that, continue with your installation.

Answer (score 0):

I remember when I first tried using Ubuntu 11.04 or later there was an issue with my laptop's ATI graphic card and the OS. I used a program called boot repair. Here is a link to a video I followed which helped me solve my problem http://youtu.be/cbIHWoJhIII.
Let me know if it helped you .